# Can I Iterate rows of a CSV to create keys paired with empty lists?

Tags: list, python-3.x, loops, csv, dictionary

**What I have:**

A CSV which I populated with rows of text, which are one word per cell.

**Micro level: Attempting:**

I am trying to create a dictionary where each row is a Key and each Key is assigned an empty list as a variable (see below).

I can do this one row at a time by converting the list to a tuple -->
creating an empty list -->
Adding the tuple to my dictionary as a key and assigning the empty list as the variable

However, I would like to do this in an automatic fashion as doing this individually is tedious.

**Macro level: Attempting:**
I want to assign a list of keywords (tags) to each row in my CSV to call upon the text later based on their tags.

**My question:**
Is there a way to do this the way I am describing?

Am I going about it wrong and should be doing this a different way?

*edit: I am thinking that if I flip this I could solve my overall issue.

For example make x amount of tags as key values for my tag dictionary and make a one time run through to assign each key with a empty dictionary value. Then populate the dictionaries with the text from my CSV.

This would not remove the one by one method; however, would reduce the amount of times I would need to enter Key/Value pairs as I am more likely to have more text than tags.

see code below

```
!#Python3

import csv
import os
import string

#open CSV and assign var to the list content
outputFile = open("output.csv", encoding="utf-8")
outputReader = csv.reader(outputFile)
data = list(outputReader)

#Get rid of empty cells
for list in data:
    for object in list:
        while "" in list:
            list.remove("")

#open a dictionary
tags = {}

#Turn first row of CSV into a tuple
article1 = tuple(data[1])

#generate empty list
article1_tags = []

#Assign empty list as a variable to the article1 Key and put in tags     dictionary
While True:
    if article1 in tags :
           break
    else:
           tags[article1] = article1_tags
```

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the point of why you need to create a dictionary of empty lists, with the key id as the text of a row from a csv? Why not just call the key row1, row2 etc and then have the value of row1 as the list of strings from row 1 from your csv. Adding some context would help.

Comment: Each row of text in my csv represents the content of an article. I want to assign multiple keywords to each row (article). For that I want an empty list which I can append to. If you see my edit, flipping this, (keywords become keys, rows go into the variable lists) saves on the amount of lists I need to create, but doesn't fully resolve my issue.

Comment: Ok well I'm guessing you are cut and pasting chunks of text from web articles into a csv file you are creating in excel? And then you want to assign tags (single word descriptors) to each article chunk so then you can cross reference and sort between articles? If thats what you want then I have a different idea. What you are attempting is messy and confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Now that I have bit more of idea of what you are trying to acheive I would suggest using a list of dictionary's. Each dictionary containing the data about each article (or row from your csv file). The key here is that a csv file is still a plain text file, there is nothing special about csv. In fact I would avoid using excel altogether and edit using a text editor.

I would start by opening the file and reading each row (line) from the file into a key/value pair of a dictionary.
The cool thing about python 3 is that you do that very easily without extra modules.

```
csvfile = open('output.csv', encoding='utf-8')
articlelist = []
for line in csvfile:
    articlelist.append(dict(textkey=line,tagskey=[]))
```

Using the iterator 'line' in this context with a text file stream object will automatically go row by row and take all the text of that line as a single string. So line is a string object here.

Once you have list of dictionary's like this you can simply iterate through the articlelist printing out or adding tags or doing whatever you wish even adding more key/value pairs to each dictionary. Doing it in this way means that not all the dictionary's need to follow the same format (although thats desirable).

I added the tagskey key and the value is an empty list which you can add to later.

Do not use infinite while loops or while loops at all to go through lists etc. Always use the

```
for iterator in theList:
```

method.

I would also look into using the JSON format for your little exercise here. I think it will lend itself much nicer to what you are trying to acheive. And with Python JSON is very easily read and then output again all using plain text. You could then output to a JSON text file manually edit it and then python read it again and process it.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I junked this model entirely. Working with a CSV was foolish. I am replacing the CSV with an SQL database. In this case sqlite3.

Comment: @DTracer fair enough. Python can still help you with sql type objects as well. And I've always found it great for working with large text files. Good luck!